# Group multidimensional array data by two values and sum another value within each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have a multi dimensional array. I need to sum up the distance values with same 'driver' and 'date' keys

```
Input : 

$firstArr = array(
0 =>array('driver'=>'xxxx',
                    'distance' => 100,
                    'vehicle' => 1,
                    'date' => '2019-10'),

1=>array('driver'=>'xxxx',
                    'distance' => 200,
                    'vehicle' => 2,
                    'date' => '2019-10'),
2=>array('driver'=>'yyyy',
                    'distance' => 100,
                    'vehicle' => 3,
                    'date' => '2019-10'));
```

Output Expected :

```
$finalArr = array(
0 =>array('driver'=>'xxxx',
                    'distance' => 300,
                    'vehicle' => '1,2',
                    'date' => '2019-10'),

1=>array('driver'=>'yyyy',
                    'distance' => 100,
                    'vehicle' => 3,
                    'date' => '2019-10'));
```

I tried below code. But the output is a datewise array.

```
$subArr = array();
foreach($firstArr as $key => $val){
$subArr[$val['driver']][$val['date']]['distance'] += $val['distance'];
$subArr[$val['driver']][$val['date']]['vehicle'] .= $val['vehicle'].',';
$subArr[$val['driver']][$val['date']]['date'] = $val['date'];
$subArr[$val['driver']][$val['date']]['driver'] = $val['driver'];

}
$result = array_values($subArr);
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dirver` and `date` as a key, [Demo](https://3v4l.org/rfoNV)

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v){
    $key = $v["driver"] . "_" . $v["date"];
    if(isset($result[$key])){
        $result[$key]["distance"] += $v["distance"];
    }else{
        $result[$key] = $v;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to sum up the distance and the vehicles by driver and date.
With the help of [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) we can set the initial array if not exists for each driver date combo and then do the processing of the required fields.

```
$keys = array_keys($input[0]);
$result = array_reduce($input, function ($sum, $row) use ($keys) {
    $key = $row['driver'] . $row['date'];
    $sum[$key] = $sum[$key] ?? array_combine($keys, [$row['driver'], null, null, $row['date']]);
    $sum[$key]['distance'] += $row['distance'];
    $sum[$key]['vehicle'] .= (($sum[$key]['vehicle']) ? ',': '' ) . $row['vehicle'];
    return $sum;
}, []);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [xxxx2019-10] => Array
        (
            [driver] => xxxx
            [distance] => 300
            [vehicle] => 1,2
            [date] => 2019-10
        )

    [yyyy2019-10] => Array
        (
            [driver] => yyyy
            [distance] => 100
            [vehicle] => 3
            [date] => 2019-10
        )

)
```